# Expected response to be a <redirect>, but was <200> in Controller test in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I know a lot of other users have posted their problem with the same title. And I have tried all their solutions too. But despite trying everything, I
am unable to get to the solution.

The messages_controller_spec:

```
context 'with valid attributes' do
  before :each do
    user = FactoryGirl.create :user
    sign_in user
  end
  it 'redirects to the root page' do
    xhr :post, :create, messages: attributes_for(:message)
    expect(response).to redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

Now My MessageController:

```
def create
  @message = current_user.messages.build(message_params)
  @recipients = User.all
  if @message.save
    redirect_to root_path, notice: "Message Sent!" #The test fails here
  else
    flash[alert] = "Great Scott!"
    render :new 
  end
end
```

Running rspec from the console gives the following error:

> Failure/Error: expect(response).to redirect_to root_path
>          Expected response to be a <:redirect> but was <200>

I have also checked the log/test.rb file. The redirection is successful. But the response is still 200 instead of 3xx:

> [1m[36m (0.3ms)[0m  [1mSAVEPOINT active_record_1[0m
>     [1m[35mSQL (1.4ms)
>   [0m  INSERT INTO "messages" ("body", "sender_id", "created_at",      "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["body", "MyText"],      ["sender_id", 1], ["created_at", "2016-10-06 11:16:14.934487"],     ["updated_at", "2016-10-06 11:16:14.934487"]]
>     [1m[36m (0.3ms)[0m  [1mRELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1[0m
>   Redirected to http://test.host/
>   Completed 200 OK in 40ms (ActiveRecord: 5.9ms)
>     [1m[35m (0.6ms)[0m  ROLLBACK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use `xhr` so it give `200`

Try Following

```
context 'with valid attributes' do
  before :each do
    user = FactoryGirl.create :user
    sign_in user
  end
  it 'redirects to the root page' do
    post :create, messages: attributes_for(:message)
    expect(response).to redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

Comment: Yeah done that. Can you explain in what situation xhr would work and why it didn't work here?

Comment: @NovneetNov when your request is ajax request in that case you use `xhr`.  But here your request is not ajax request. it simple post request and after success it redirect to root_path.

Comment: Okay got it. xhr is for ajax request. Hence it returns 200.

Comment: In addition to the answer above, I just want to point out you should be using _url for redirects, not _path, in accordance with [HTTP spec](https://www.viget.com/articles/rails-named-routes-path-vs-url)

Comment: Good Point! Thank you.